# How to migrate a createComponents from Lucene 4.5 to 8.20

Tags: lucene

I had the below code written using Lucene 4.5.0 and i am trying to upgrade to 8.2.0

Lucene 4.5 code:

```
@Override
protected Analyzer.TokenStreamComponents createComponents(final String fieldName, final Reader reader)
{
    final StandardTokenizer src = new StandardTokenizer(this.matchVersion, reader);
    src.setMaxTokenLength(this.maxTokenLength);
    TokenStream tok = new StandardFilter(this.matchVersion, src);
    tok = new StopFilter(this.matchVersion, tok, this.stopwords);
    return new Analyzer.TokenStreamComponents(src, tok)
    {
        @Override
        protected void setReader(final Reader reader)
                throws IOException
        {
            src.setMaxTokenLength(StandardAnalyzerWithoutLowercaseFilter.this.maxTokenLength);
            super.setReader(reader);
        }
    };
}
```

How can i convert the above code to fit in lucene 8.2.0 since StandardFilter is no longer present in the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

Since 4.0, `StandardFilter` didn't actually do anything, so they finally got rid of it. You can safely just delete that line.

Jira issue: [LUCENE-8356](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-8356).